# using msfvenom to encode an exe file without any payload, like oldy msfencode (packing)

Tags: metasploit, detection

Doing some research about packing and such, I went on the possibility to use the old msfencode to generate a packed exe.

However, msfencode is not updated anymore (still found on kali however), and I wish to use the encoders on the x64 architecture.

By the way, I tested to use msfvenom simply to pack my executable, using the 'no payload' option as such : '-p -'. But, it just keeps asking me to supply a payload on stdin.

So, is it possible to just pack a binary using msfvenom?

Comment: The -p- isn't for empty payload. Rather it is for taking the payload from stdin (standard input). msfvenom or msfencode isn't for packaging, it is for generating and encoding payloads in different formats.

Answer (score 5):

I would advise to use following command:

```
msfvenom -p generic/custom PAYLOADFILE=[path_to_file] -a [architecture] --platform [platform] -e [encoder]
```

bear in mind you can list all possible encoders with:

```
msfvenom --list encoders
```

this is an example of encoding a shellcode using add/sub encoder, which I tested working:

```
msfvenom -p generic/custom PAYLOADFILE=./shellcode.bin -a x86 --platform windows -e x86/add_sub -f raw -o shellcode-encoded.bin
```

Answer (score 1):

To use `-p -`, you need to supply the shellcode on stdin by:

Syntax:

```
cat <shellcode_file> | msfvenom -b <bad_chars> -e <encoder> -f <format> -a <arch> --platform <platform> -p -
```

Example:

```
cat shellcode | msfvenom -b '\x00' -e x86/shikata_ga_nai -f py -a x86 --platform windows -p -
```